# Android app splash screen not going to desired activity

Tags: android

Well, my splash screen does not direct you to desired activity (register page) and directs you to the main event.

Here is the code for the android manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="noor.kaspar.lessonary">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="noor.kaspar.lessonary.SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="noor.kaspar.lessonary.Login"/>
        <activity android:name="noor.kaspar.lessonary.Register"/>
        <activity android:name="noor.kaspar.lessonary.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my splash screen code:

```
package noor.kaspar.lessonary;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Register.class));
                    finish();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);

    }


}
```

And finally, here is my register code (i'm using firebase):

```
package noor.kaspar.lessonary;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;




public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mName, mEmail, mPassword, mSchool, mDateOfBirth;
    Button mRegister;
    TextView mLoginText;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mSchool = findViewById(R.id.school);
        mDateOfBirth = findViewById(R.id.dateOfBirth);
        mRegister = findViewById(R.id.register);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mProgressBar2 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required!");
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required!");
                }
                if(password.length() < 6){
                    mPassword.setError("Password must be at least 6 characters long!");
                }

                mProgressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Register the user in firebase

                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registering was successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Oops, an error has accured!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });






    }
}
```

And here is the main activitys code (it's in kotlin):

```
package noor.kaspar.lessonary

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already have a session active. Try putting a breakpoint or log inside the getcurrentuser conditional. If it is going to Main Activity is probably because you have an active  session and this code is running:

```
if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

You should probably add a log out functionality so firebase can sign out. you can do this by calling `fAuth.signOut();`

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that `fAuth.getCurrentUser()` returns `null` in `Register.java`? There are a few edge cases [according to the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#java):

[image: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#java]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! This may indeed be the problem, but how am I supposed to attach an AuthStateListener to the authcheck?

Comment: Hi again @KasparNoor! :-) I'm not completely sure what problem we're trying to solve here - does the given user found in `Register.java` not work when used in `MainActivity.kt`?

Comment: @KasparNoor: Don't forget to mark an answer as "Accepted" if it helped you solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Well, nothing wrong with your splash screen. The issue is that your checking if `FirebaseAuth` is null in your Register `onCreate` method which is might not be null:

```
if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

So move the above code to your splashscreen(which is where I think you should check the value of `auth` . So I modified your splashscreen like:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                checkAuth();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);

}
private void checkAuth(){
 FirebaseAuth fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }else{
     startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
        finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! But this has somehow not solved my problem, I'm thoroughly confused. 

So I modified the splash screen as You said, but it still takes me to the main activity.
I read from the documentation that there are some edge cases, where it returns something else instead of null, so I should attach AuthStateListener to it, but I have no idea how to actually implement that. If you could guide me, that would be helpful.

Cheers
Kaspar